# How can make myself sure that I can apply Conservation of Momentum in a system?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws

How do I know  I can apply Conservation of Momentum in the System  ?
And What happens if there is a Impulse in the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no net external force acting on the system, the momentum is always conserved. The energy needs not be conserved for the momentum to be conserved. The only necessary condition is zero net impulse on the system from all the external forces.

Comment: If energy is not conserved, momentum cannot be conserved. If possible, show a contradiction.

Comment: Absolutely. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inelastic_collision

Comment: You're right. I forgot about collisions.

Answer (score 1):

In particular, ensure no external force acts on the system.

If there is an impulse on the system, there will be a net acceleration. Use Newton's Laws then.

Comment: I'd rather say "ensure that the sum of the external forces is zero", to be more general.